# Convert continuous time-series data into daily-hourly representation using R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have time-series data in xts representation as

```
 library(xts)
 xtime <-timeBasedSeq('2015-01-01/2015-01-30 23')
 df <- xts(rnorm(length(xtime),30,4),xtime)
```

Now I want to calculate co-orelation between different days, and hence I want to represent `df` in matrix form as:

[image]

To achieve this I used

```
p_mat= split(df,f="days",drop=FALSE,k=1)
```

Using this I get a list of days, but I am not able to arrange this list in matrix form. Also I used

```
p_mat<- df[.indexday(df) %in% c(1:30) & .indexhour(df) %in% c(1:24)]
```

With this I do not get any output.
Also I tried to use `rollapply()`, but was not able to arrange it properly.

May I get help to form the matrix using xts/zoo objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using a helper function that will account for days that do not have 24 observations.

```
library(xts)
xtime <- timeBasedSeq('2015-01-01/2015-01-30 23')
set.seed(21)
df <- xts(rnorm(length(xtime),30,4), xtime)

tHourly <- function(x) {
  # initialize result matrix for all 24 hours
  dnames <- list(format(index(x[1]), "%Y-%m-%d"),
                 paste0("H", 0:23))
  res <- matrix(NA, 1, 24, dimnames = dnames)
  # transpose day's rows and set colnames
  tx <- t(x)
  colnames(tx) <- paste0("H", .indexhour(x))
  # update result object and return
  res[,colnames(tx)] <- tx
  res
}
# split on days, apply tHourly to each day, rbind results
p_mat <- split(df, f="days", drop=FALSE, k=1)
p_list <- lapply(p_mat, tHourly)
p_hmat <- do.call(rbind, p_list)
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could use something like this:

```
#convert to a data.frame with an hour column and a day column
df2 <- data.frame(value = df, 
                  hour = format(index(df), '%H:%M:%S'), 
                  day  = format(index(df), '%Y:%m:%d'),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#then use xtabs which ouputs a matrix in the format you need
tab <- xtabs(value ~ day + hour, df2)
```

Output:

```
            hour
day          00:00:00 01:00:00 02:00:00 03:00:00 04:00:00 05:00:00 06:00:00 07:00:00 08:00:00 09:00:00 10:00:00 11:00:00 12:00:00
  2015:01:01 28.15342 35.72913 27.39721 29.17048 28.42877 28.72003 28.88355 31.97675 29.29068 27.97617 35.37216 29.14168 29.28177
  2015:01:02 23.85420 28.79610 27.88688 27.39162 29.77241 22.34256 34.70633 23.34011 28.14588 25.53632 26.99672 38.34867 30.06958
  2015:01:03 37.47716 31.70040 29.04541 34.23393 33.54569 27.52303 38.82441 28.97989 24.30202 29.42240 30.83015 39.23191 30.42321
  2015:01:04 24.13100 32.08409 29.36498 35.85835 26.93567 28.27915 26.29556 29.29158 31.60805 27.07301 33.32149 25.16767 25.80806
  2015:01:05 32.16531 29.94640 32.04043 29.34250 31.68278 28.39901 24.51917 33.95135 36.07898 28.76504 24.98684 32.56897 29.82116
  2015:01:06 18.44432 27.43807 32.28203 29.76111 29.60729 32.24328 25.25417 34.38711 29.97862 32.82924 34.13643 30.89392 26.48517
  2015:01:07 34.58491 20.38762 32.29096 31.49890 28.29893 33.80405 28.44305 28.86268 33.42964 36.87851 31.08022 28.31126 25.24355
  2015:01:08 33.67921 31.59252 28.36989 35.29703 27.19507 27.67754 25.99571 27.32729 33.78074 31.73481 34.02064 28.43953 31.50548
  2015:01:09 28.46547 36.61658 36.04885 30.33186 32.26888 25.90181 31.29203 34.17445 30.39631 28.18345 27.37687 29.85631 34.27665
  2015:01:10 30.68196 26.54386 32.71692 28.69160 23.72367 28.53020 35.45774 28.66287 32.93100 33.78634 30.01759 28.59071 27.88122
  2015:01:11 32.70907 31.51985 29.22881 36.31157 32.38494 25.30569 29.37743 22.32436 29.21896 19.63069 35.25601 27.45783 28.28008
  2015:01:12 29.96676 30.51542 29.41650 29.34436 37.05421 33.05035 34.44572 26.30717 30.65737 34.61930 29.77391 21.48256 31.37938
  2015:01:13 33.46089 34.29776 37.58262 27.58801 28.43653 28.33511 28.49737 28.53348 28.81729 35.76728 27.20985 28.44733 32.61015
  2015:01:14 22.96213 32.27889 36.44939 23.45088 26.88173 27.43529 27.27547 21.86686 32.00385 23.87281 29.90001 32.37194 29.20722
  2015:01:15 28.30359 30.94721 20.62911 33.84679 27.58230 26.98849 23.77755 24.18443 30.22533 32.03748 21.60847 25.98255 32.14309
  2015:01:16 23.52449 29.56138 31.76356 35.40398 24.72556 31.45754 30.93400 34.77582 29.88836 28.57080 25.41274 27.93032 28.55150
  2015:01:17 25.56436 31.23027 25.57242 31.39061 26.50694 30.30921 28.81253 25.26703 30.04517 33.96640 36.37587 24.50915 29.00156
...and so on
```

Comment: It works perfectly. But, I do not want to convert my xts object to  data frame, because this slows down my computations. I believe using `split` or `indexday`  I should be able to represent it. I will wait for the answer using these, otherwise I will go for `xtabs`

Comment: I dont think using `data.frame` would take that long, not even for 1m rows. Saving the dates outside of tha dataframe and then using format to create the rest of the columns will make it even faster since you will use `index` only once.